# Global Review Queue

Tags: feature-request, review

Many StackExchange users are active contributors and/or moderators on multiple StackExchange sites.  Generally, this means that the user has multiple sites where they are able (and, quite probably, willing) to perform or assist with moderator duties via the `/review` queue.

For example, I myself have the following Review queue privileges:

- First Posts / Late Answers:  22 sites
- Close Votes / Reopen Votes:  5 sites
- Low Quality / Suggested Edits:  5 sites

To facilitate and encourage us to go through the Review queues when we have privileges on multiple sites, I'd like to see a StackExchange Global Review Queue.  I believe this queue could exist in one of two forms:

- A consolidation of all Review queues to which a user is privileged.  This would allow the user to seamlessly cruise through the Review actions on all sites where they have privileges to act.
- A portal (with return link on per-site Review queues) to all Review queues to which a user is privileged.  This would allow the user to browse through the Review queues of each site from a central location, without necessarily having to clear the queue of one site before moving to the next.

Could a feature like this be implemented?

Comment: Meh. I'm a mod on several sites and a participant on many, and I don't feel the need. I tend to use different queues on different sites. For example, I hardly ever review (apart from suggested edits and the occasional closing) on sites where I'm a mod.

Comment: I've just started doing more reviews of late and would definitely like to see a global queue. I find it annoying to have to switch tabs to look at the /review queues. As a user of the site I'm seeing the /review queue as a special case of the "unanswered questions" one would look at when coming into a site. It's been much easier to engage questions/answers among the sites using the review queue than the other mechanisms for bringing questions to my attention.

Answer (score 15):

Going from site to site on a per review basis would be extremely jarring, the required mindset is different for each site to determine appropriate actions. Also this really seems like a plea to make abusing the system for badges to be made easier rather than improve the quality of SE sites.

I see no benefit to consolidating multiple sites to a single queue unless you goal is to do as many reviews as quickly as possible, which is a [persistent problem that needs to be eliminated not encouraged.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-abuse)

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I like the idea, as long as it is in conjunction with improving the way the review queueueue works - give us context!

Currently I need to pop into each one of my main sites and check queueueues - and if I don't have much time I just don't bother every day.

Comment: +1 for proper use of repeating vowels.

Comment: @ScottPack He's a Brit... they love them queues so bad, they put a queue in a queue (I smell a yo dawg pic coming up...).

Comment: @yoda: Personally, I prefer to use the more correct queueueueueueueueueueueue. To each their own, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

I don't necessarily want a single merged queue (that does seem kind of squirrelly), but I do wish that there was a simple way to tell if any one of my queues has a review item.  Currently I have to select each review page individually and refresh it.  It would be nice if there was a place that I could go and be notified that there was a new item to review.  It's all right if I then have to click through to it.  The hard part is finding out that there's a review queued.

It would also be nice if the same page would tell me about new questions on sites that I follow.  So I could click through, see if the question is relevant to me, and then take the appropriate action (answer, edit, request close, whatever).

This kind of page would make it easier for good reviewers to find items that need review.  Since it would notify as soon as it got one review, people would have more time to review.  Lots of the time now, I get several reviews at once, as I don't poll my queues every minute.