# 'Prepare for Archive' review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, old-questions

This feature request is prompted by two recent Meta.Chem.SE posts, dealing with [old 'Welcome!' comments](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2864/shouldnt-we-cull-welcome-comments) left on new posts and with [explicit "**EDIT:**" notations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2872/i-question-the-inclusion-of-edit-statements-in-the-posts) added to questions and answers when edits are made.  In both situations, the now-nuisance content was acceptable to (at least a subset of) the community when it was first posted, but is now obsolete and would be better excised from the question/answers.

I propose a 'Prepare for Archive' review queue, for questions that have seen no content activity (no new answers, and no edits or comments to the question or any answers) for some set period of time after having been initially asked/answered/discussed -- perhaps one week?  This queue would prompt community members to, e.g., flag obsolete comments and to clean up "**EDIT:** or other notation that is undesirable.

While these two examples are only from one SE site, I think the feature could be useful more broadly.  Each site's community (or, perhaps just the leadership) could define the scope of the queue for that site.

To avoid the edits made out of such a queue just then being punted to the Suggested Edits queue, I would suggest a minimum rep of no less than 2k to gain access to this queue; perhaps even higher.  The 'done reviewing' buttons would be similar to those in the 'First Posts' and 'Late Answers' queues. At this point, I'm envisioning that each question would go through this queue only once in its lifetime.

---

For completeness, there are a few feature requests of various ages for new review queues already on Meta.SE:

- [Old question review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257131/old-question-review-queue)
- [Add review queue for recent migrations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149825/add-review-queue-for-recent-migrations)
- [Global Review Queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157638/global-review-queue)
- [Add "Questions edited after closing" review task](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143013/add-questions-edited-after-closing-review-task)
- ["New user in trouble" review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183618/new-user-in-trouble-review-queue)
- ["New Users" review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153530/new-users-review-queue)

None of these appear to be what I'm envisioning.

Comment: +1, but I think reviews were intended to signify possible BIG problems in posts. A site like [so] would need 50000 reviews per week, so not really sure if this is practical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Review queues are useful when you want multiple people to take a look at the post, and arrive at a decision about what's to be done about them.

An attempt to [adapt the review format for janitorial tasks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287466) has been a spectacular failure.

A task like removing "edit:" from inactive posts is a solitary activity. Sure, you'd like to promote it on the meta, perhaps with a featured post and/or dedicated chatroom for discussion of the process... but ultimately, it's up to any user to decide this is what they want to do.

What may be lacking is the will to do this; a way to find the posts is already there.

- Search: [edit: lastactive:..14d](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=edit%3a%20lastactive%3a..7d) to get the posts that were inactive for two weeks and contain this text.
- SEDE query: [Welcome comments on old posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/chemistry/query/345127/welcome-comments-on-old-posts) shows the comments with "Welcome to" on the posts inactive for two weeks.

(Incidentally: one week is not long enough to consider the matter settled; a large number of posts get deleted after 9 days, so polishing them prior to deletion is pointless. One may want to exclude closed posts from the above, which is easy to do.)

Comment: Is there a tutorial on constructing SE search filters somewhere?

Comment: Also, is there a document somewhere (or a good way to search, say, the SE blog) summarizing the rationales behind all the various SE features? Or is it just a hard slog through the blog backfiles to reread the history of the discussion?

Comment: Help Center has a page on searching: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/searching  There is no "why we have all these features" document, other than this site, [meta.se] itself.